# How to add Ternary Operator with a class in a single classname

Tags: reactjs, conditional-operator

```
 className="app__header app__flex"

 className={darkMode ? "dark-mode" : "light-mode"}
```

I want to combine these two classname

```
 className={"app__header app__flex" + {darkMode ? "dark-mode" : "light-mode"} }
```

but it gives me error

Comment: Does it work if you replace the inner curly braces with parentheses? i.e. `className={"app__header app__flex" + (darkMode ? "dark-mode" : "light-mode") }`.

Comment: You're using `{` where the valid syntax would be `(` (Or alternatively, do the whole thing in a [template string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals))

Comment: combine two classNames with space or without space?

Comment: Use the [classNames](https://www.npmjs.com/package/classnames) npm package.

Answer (score 0):

```
className={darkMode ? "app__header app__flex dark-mode" : "app__header app__flex light-mode"}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
className={`app__header app__flex ${darkMode ? "dark-mode" : "light-mode"}`
```